# char[] password getters and setters to a String

Tags: java, arrays, database, char, getter-setter

I have a typical `char[]` password variable with getters and setters. I have done this so that my password variable is never shown in plain text.

```
private String passwordAsString;
private char[] password;

public char[] getPassword() { return password; }
public void setPassword(char[] password) { this.password = password; }
```

I want to send my password to a database, but I believe it needs to be sent as a String type. So, I decided to create a new variable called `PasswordAsString`. Is there a better approach? This seems sloppy.

Secondly my getPasswordAsString is not returning the password as a String. What I have so far is:

```
public void setPasswordAsString(String passwordAsString) {
        this.passwordAsString = passwordAsString;
    }

    public String getPasswordAsString() {
        return password.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Side note: when taking and returning your password arrays you might want to consider sending and making a copy of the array.

Comment: You don't need any other variable. You already have the password in your char array. All you need is to create a String from that char array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-

Comment: The usual reason for keeping passwords in objects of type `char[]` is to *avoid* putting them in `String`s, which cannot be cleared and which may hang around in the VM's memory for an indeterminate amount of time even after they are no longer reachable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger how can you send password to the array as char[] though?

Answer (score 1):

The getter/setter for the password as a `String` could be implemented like this:

```
public void setPasswordAsString(String passwordAsString) {
    this.password = passwordAsString.toCharArray();
}

public String getPasswordAsString() {
    return new String(password);
}
```

These get and set the `char[] password` field directly – no need for a `passwordAsString` field. Convert from `char[]` to `String` with [`new String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) and from `String` to `char[]` with [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

I'm pretty sure that passing around the password as a `String` like this defeats any security purpose for using a `char` array, though.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Passing the password as a string defeats the purpose, but how else can you store it in the database? You can't pass an array to the database.

Comment: @JMullen If you're storing plaintext passwords in your database, you have much bigger security problems.

Answer (score 0):

A char array's toString() method is not going to get you what you want. Instead, construct a new String:

```
public String getPasswordAsString() {
    return new String(password);
}
```

Also, I would probably consider not including a setter for the passwordAsString field (or having a second field at all, for that matter), as this goes against what you are attempting to accomplish here.